Android, how to launch application via Google Assistant?
I'm implementing an application and they are providing their app through their Website, not from Google Play Console.
I just wanted to integrate Google Assistant into that application. All I need to do is run my application using the google assistant. I read in the documentation that this does not require adding any changes to the code, provided that the main activity is in the manifest contains:
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

However, my application does not launch with Google Assistant. This gave me the assumption that the problem was that my application was not published in the Google Store. Could this be related to this?
Also, can I use Google Assistant in this case? Do I need to register the application in the App Actions console?

Are you referring to: https://developer.android.com/develop/devices/assistant/overview "Hey Google, open AppName" which requires app being published on Play Store? Or some other App Action: https://developer.android.com/develop/devices/assistant/overview#app_actions

I need  "Hey Google, open AppName". Аnd I don’t understand whether this can be implemented without publishing the application on Play Store

The Google voice assistant uses the Google cloud (and subject to changes in behavior by Google, i.e. Gemini or whatever AI feature they are testing/using) so Google Assistant only knows about "xyz app" if that app is in the (Google service) Play Store.

@Morrison Chang, Do I understand correctly that in my case I will not be able to use Google Assistant to launch my application?

Correct, as I understand the documentation provided, you need to have your app in the Google Play Store to have a voice command launch your "AppName". I believe Google is using the cloud to do speech-to-text especially on lower end devices rather than on-device speech-to-text. Be aware that while Google has documented expected behavior / API, the Google Assistant has changed end-user behavior which some frequency and as documented in the link for App Actions, its execution at their discretion.
